# Clean pattern for localizing sentences in Rails i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization

I have the following sentence I need to localize:

> you have U unread message/s and N new message/s

Example localization

U 0 N 1

"you have 1 new message"

U 1 N 1

"you have 1 unread message and 1 new message"

U 1 N 0

"you have 1 unread message"

U 2 N 0

"you have 1 unread messages"

I can easily get started with this mess

```
unread_only: 
  one: you have 1 unread message
  other: you have {{count}} unread messages 

new_only: 
  one: you have 1 new message
  other: you have {{count}} new messages
```

... at this point I am stuck

```
# how do I pass two counts in?
new_and_unread:
```

I am aware i18n in Rails is not ICU MessageFormat, however, is there some sane way of localizing this with the tools we have? Can you pass 2 counts into a localization switch?

Comment: I don't think many frameworks deal with this, because it explodes; I suspect rails is no exception.  Imagine localizing to Arabaic where you'd need 36 localized strings in your example, which is near unworkable.  Not technical enough for an answer, but I suspect the best course would be to re-think that string even in English.

Comment: The main accepted solution for this is ICU message format: https://github.com/jedtoolkit/messageformat.js

Comment: The Stack Overflow Careers i18n API allows only one count for exactly this reason. Anytime more were needed, we changed the English to require just one.

Answer (score 5):

My first thought is to use something like:

```
unread: 
  one: 1 unread message
  other:{{count}} unread messages 

new: 
  one: 1 new message
  other: {{count}} new messages 


I18n.t('you_have') << [msg1,msg2].map(&:presence).compact.join(I18n.t('and'))
```

But this probably won't work for every language. Just western ones.

Here is more info:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations

```
new_and_unread: "You have %{new} new, and %{unread} unread messages"

<%=t 'new_and_unread', :new => 1, :unread => 3 %>
```

Comment: yeah it feels like this is putting us in a corner later on

Comment: I think you need to provide keys for each case. 1n1u, 1n2u, 2n1u, 2n2u

Comment: huge pita, I may add this in for these cases if its small enough https://github.com/jedtoolkit/messageformat.js